# Vim - save and close buffer in one command

Tags: vim, buffer

I have a bunch of text files in a directory and I know I'll need to edit each one individually.

I start at the command line with:

```
vim *.txt
```

Which opens the files as separate buffers in Vim and leaves me looking at the first one. I edit it, then I use ':w' to save it and ':bd' to close the buffer and move on to the next one.

This ':w:bd' to save and close the buffer feels long to me, and I suspect there's a more Vim ninja way of doing it. What's the recommended way to save and close the buffer you are working on in one felt swoop?

Comment: My recomended way would be to just move to the `:next` buffer and write/close everything once your task is finished with `:wqa`. This supposes that you have `:set hidden` in your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: @romainl: not as useful, because if you open 30 buffers for editing, you have to keep track of how many you've cycled through.

Comment: @naught101, I'm not sure why you think that. `:wqa` will write and quit every argument in the argument list but with a single command versus 30.

Comment: Ah, I see. Was confused, because I'm used to using `:bnext`, and that loops after the last open buffer. Yes, `:n` is good.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When passing the files to Vim on the command-line, they are not only opened in buffers, but also populate the *argument list*. Therefore, you can use commands like `:next` and `:first` to navigate through them (and `:argdo` for batch processing, which can be a nifty trick). The command I recommend for your question is `:wnext` (short form `:wn`), which `:write`s the current buffer and then goes to the `:next` one.

You don't need to explicitly `:bdelete` a buffer, especially not when you're launching Vim from the command-line with a set of files and then quit it when you're done. (The only exceptions I can think of is unloading a huge file to save system memory, or re-using a single GVIM instance for many different edits.)

However, if you really want this, just define a custom command, e.g.

```
:command Wd write|bdelete
```

Comment: You've mentioned two methods of achieving what the OP requested, but the second one isn't obvious: `:w|bd`.

Comment: --> This has the advantage of fitting the approach the OP uses, although I'd agree `:next` makes more sense in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

While I agree that you don't *have* to delete open buffers you aren't currently using, I like to delete them because I have [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline)'s tab line enabled, which shows all open buffers all the time at the top of the window. I have the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap qq :w\|bd<cr>
```

`qq` saves and closes the current buffer, but also messes with the "record macro" functionality of vim (which I'm okay with).

Comment: The built-in `ZZ` comes to mind, but that ends up saving and quitting Vim entirely, rather than just deleting the buffer. Lowercase `zz` might be an interesting alternative mapping, for anyone who finds macros more valuable than centering the view on the current cursor line.

Comment: I recently changed it to `Q`, after realizing just how valuable recording in Vim can be.

Answer (score 2):

I use `abbreviation` instead of a `command`

```
cnorea wd w\|bd
```

So I can see what it is actually doing when I hit space after typing `:wd`, or if I want to be fast I just press enter, it still does the conversion.